# Laravel 4 undefined method Request::forged()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.

I have a filter:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
  if (Request::forged()) return Response::error('500');
});
```

and in a controller I'm calling the filter for POST requests:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

but I get this error when I'm POSTing:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::forged()
```

Can anyone give me some insight into what is going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example is referring to Laravel 3. Here how you should be using it on Laravel 4 https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/filters.php#L74-L80